# PYTHON: I'm trying to read different values from XML files and send to Django Html template

Tags: python, html, django

I have already read the xml values but i think that the way which i'm using to store the data is wrong. I'need to store a list, or a dict or list of dict some values and then send to the HTML Template and render an HTML Table with all the values:

this should be the result and the following code is how i'm actual reading the values from XML

```
for files in file_in_path:
fileP = os.path.join(path,files)
tree = ET.parse(fileP)
roots = tree.getroot()
for x in roots.findall('DatiGeneraliDocumento'): //node of xml file that i need to read
    tipdoc = x.find('TipoDocumento').text //all the data
    numdoc = x.find('Numero').text 
    datadoc = x.find('Data').text
    mydict = {"tipdoc":item,"numdoc":numdoc,"datadoc":datadoc} //then i'm trying to save in dict
    liste.append(mydict)//and append all to a list
context = {"data":liste}
```

return(response, "page.html", context)

when i'm in my html page and trying to print the result with django format language
"{{ data }}" he print out one value and not all of of them, but if in python file i print out my list he print out all list. which is the best way to store all the values in all the xml files and then print out in a html table?

Comment: instead of `{{data}}` can you try:
`
{% for item in data %}
<table>
your rows and cells...
{{item}} comes here
{% endfor %}
`
I'm not surely understand the problem but something like this should work

Comment: The real problem isn't in the html template, but in the way which i'm using to store the data inside the list. so, HOW CAN I SAVE MY RESULTS AFTER THAT I'VE READ FROM XML??